# What can be improved in this question?

Tags: support

Question in question is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25062428/comparing-two-objects-by-iterating-recursively-through-all-the-properties-prope).

I got 60%-voted to be closed and I can't see why. Since the closevoters didn't bother to hint, I'd love an opinion so I can improve it.

Comment: Take a look at the reason they used when voting to close.  You have 250 rep, you can see it.

Comment: @Servy I can do that?! How?

Comment: @KonradViltersten for that, you click "close" link under your question and explore dialog that pops up: it will show number of votes cast for the reasons listed in there (close that dialog without casting a vote if you only want to explore). FWIW at a brief glance your question seems to be at cross-road between Stack Overflow, Code Review and Code Golf, and it feels like a bit lacking something that would make it a definitive fit for one of these sites (wish I could point a finger on what exactly is missing, but I can't, guess close voters also feel something like this choosing "too broad")

Comment: @gnat Great hint! I'd never click there because I thought I'd immediately vote for my question to be closed, hehe. Now I've seen the reason for votes (or, rather, "reason") but it made me none the wiser, hehe. I guess I can just disregard the votes for closure, since there's no way to determine for sure what to improve. Thanks for trying, matie!   :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you got a satisfactory answer to your question, and your question has a net score of zero, the close votes are irrelevant.

Comment: They're relevant to me because I've got the ambition to post perfect contributions. Pride, mate. Pride!   :)

Comment: I've read that question bans take into account questions that have been voted down to zero. Someone trying to avoid being banned from asking questions might want to make sure that all questions have a positive score.